# .htaccess ErrorDocument 404 not redirecting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have tried to create a custom page for the 404 errors to go to, these are the settings in my apache2.conf

```
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html>
options Index FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and this is my code in the .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteRule ^ls/(\w+)/?$ Pages/misc/profile.php?ss=$1 [NC]
```

however when I test a page that doesn't exist and it 404s, it doesn't redirect at all to 404.php. For instance if I try a random page like asdf.html, it doesn't show the custom 404 page or even say can't find 404.php, it says it can't find asdf.html which means the redirect never takes place. Can anyone shed some light on why it doesn't redirect?

Thank - you!

p.s. my website resides in /var/www/html for reference

Comment: What OS are you using? Apache 2 version? I reproduced your setup (for /var/www/html) on Ubuntu 15.04 with the latest apache2 version (2.4.10) and it works as expected, i.e. calling 404.php for not found pages. The only difference is that I specified `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks` instead of `options Index FollowSymLinks` for the directory, because the server didn't start otherwise.

Comment: Is your .htaccess file definitely being obeyed?